# TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am pretty new to Angular and have problems with making a synchronous operation. I have resolved few issues which came my way with the angular controller, where I get the error 'Cannot call method then of undefined' thrown from the newController file.

```
angular.module('newApp.newController', ['angularSpinner', 'ui.bootstrap'])

.controller('newController', function($q, $scope, utilityFactory, $http) {
    utilityFactory.getData().then(function(data) {

        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);

    });
});


angular.module('newApp.utility', [])
    .factory('utilityFactory', function($q, $http) {

        var utils = {};

        //This is a cordova plugin
        var getLauncher = function() {
            return window.plugin.launcher;
        };

        var success = function(data) {
            console.log(device);
            return device;
        }
        var fail = function(error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        };

        utils.getData = function() {
            /* Get the store number details initially before initalizing the application */
            if (window.plugin) {
                var launcher = getLauncher();
                console.log("Fetching data from device");
                //Cordova js is returning this method
                return launcher.getDevice(success, fail);
            }
        };
        return utils;
    })
```

Comment: `getData` is not returning anything

Comment: I used this as well


  return  launcher.getDevice(success, fail);

Comment: But it won't return anything for `else` and what does `launcher.getDevice` return?

Comment: Launcher.prototype.getDevice = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    exec(successCallback, failureCallback, KEY, 'getDevice', []);
};

Comment: 'launcher.getDevice' returns device related information from android phone like macId

Comment: @Bharath Are you using 'ngCordova' plugin by any chance? If so, I think it needs to be used in a completely different way. If not, I could not find any api - window.plugin.launcher.getDevice - anywhere related to Cordova. Can you please mention the source of that API?

Answer (score 5):

With the understanding that :

```
Launcher.prototype.getDevice = function(successCallback, failureCallback) {
    exec(successCallback, failureCallback, KEY, 'getDevice', []);
}
```

, we know that `window.plugin.launcher.getDevice()` returns `undefined`, not a data object. Instead, it provides its response via its success/failure callbacks.

Therefore, to work with promises, `window.plugin.launcher.getDevice()` needs to be "promisified", involving the explicit creation of a `new Promise()` and its resolution/rejection by .getDevice's callbacks. (Simply wrapping in $q(...) is not the same thing, and won't work).

```
angular.module('newApp.utility', []).factory('utilityFactory', function($q, $http) {
    return {
        getDevice: function() {
            return $q.defer(function(resolve, reject) {
                window.plugin.launcher.getDevice(resolve, reject); // If this line throws for whatever reason, it will be automatically caught internally by Promise, and `reject(error)` will be called. Therefore you needn't explicitly fork for cases where `window.plugin` or `window.plugin.launcher` doesn't exist.
            }).promise;
        }
    };
});
```

Calling from the controller should now work :

```
angular.module('newApp.newController', ['angularSpinner', 'ui.bootstrap']).controller('newController', function($q, $scope, utilityFactory, $http) {
    return utilityFactory.getDevice().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: By passing the Promise's `resolve` and `reject` functions as the successCallback and errorCallback of `window.plugin.launcher.getDevice()`.

Comment: 'ReferenceError: Promise is not defined'

Got this error

Comment: Whoops, I was assuming ES6 promises. Try the same with a $q promise. ie `return $q.defer(function(resolve, reject) {...}).promise;`

Comment: This way it is not working and not throwing any error as well. But simply the response is not reaching the scope of the controller

Comment: Is that `exec(successCallback, failureCallback, KEY, 'getDevice', []);` command documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
    return launcher.getDevice(success, fail);
```

this line is the issue, I would just wrap it with a promise:

```
    return $q(launcher.getDevice.bind(launcher, success, fail));
```

**Edit:** also you need to take care of else condition, so code would be:

```
    utils.getData = function() {
        /* Get the store number details initially before initalizing the application */
        if (window.plugin) {
            var launcher = getLauncher();
            console.log("Fetching data from device");
            //Cordova js is returning this method
            return $q(launcher.getDevice.bind(launcher, success, fail));
        }
        return $q.resolve(); // or $q.reject(reason);
    };
```

Comment: I will check on this.

Comment: Tried this, after calling getDevice method it goes into error callback function and prints the message - "Error"

Answer (score 1):

1) Your actual Module should be "newApp", not "newApp.newController" and 'newApp.utility'. That is placing those two components into separate modules instead of in the myApp module.

2) You should only use the syntax of

```
angular.module('newApp', [])
```

whenever you are declaring a new module. When you want to access the module, you should use

```
angular.module('newApp')
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

3) Your utilityFactory is returning a variable 'device' that hasn't been declared anywhere

4) You can't use 'then' without returning a promise in your getData function. Then is a method that is implemented in Javascript promises, so you can't just use it anywhere in your code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```
utils.getData = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (window.plugin) {
        var launcher = getLauncher();
        console.log("Fetching data from device");
        //Cordova js is returning this method
        return launcher.getDevice(success, fail);
    }

    return deferred.promise;    
};
```

Here is a codepen I used when debugging your code. I modified your code a little, but it will give an example of the function working when returning a promise. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNEEyx?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers mentioned, you need to return a `Promise` from your `utils.getData` function. Angular's `$q` helper lets you do just that. However, the way that some of the other answers are showing you to do it goes against best practices. When using `$q`, best practice is to do the following:

```
var myPromise = $q(function (resolve, reject) {
    // Do some logic in here that is asynchronous and either invoke resolve with
    // the results or reject with an error that may have occurred
});
```

Therefore, your code becomes:

```
angular.module('newApp.utility', [])
    .factory('utilityFactory', function($q, $http) {

        var utils = {};

        //This is a cordova plugin
        var getLauncher = function() {
            return window.plugin.launcher;
        };

        var success = function(data) {
            console.log(device);
            return device;
        }
        var fail = function(error) {
            console.log("error", error);
        };

        utils.getData = function() {
            /* Get the store number details initially before initalizing the application */
            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (!window.plugin) {
                    // You can handle this case as a rejection of the promise
                    reject(new Error('Window plugin not found'));
                    return;
                }

                var launcher = getLauncher();
                console.log("Fetching data from device");
                //Cordova js is returning this method
                // When device is ready it will "resolve" the promise and
                // invoke any of the ".then()" functions you add to the promise
                // If an error occurs, it will invoke any ".catch()" functions
                // that you have added.
                launcher.getDevice(resolve, reject);
            });
        };
        return utils;
    })
```

For more information on the `$q` service, check this post out from the official AngularJS documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Also, some resources if you want to learn more about promises and asynchronous programming in JavaScript:

Neat visualization tool for Promises - http://bevacqua.github.io/promisees/#

Tutorial on promises - https://www.toptal.com/javascript/javascript-promises

Another thing to look into as a general guide for AngularJS best practices is the angular style-guide by John Papa: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Lastly, the way you have your modules setup is slightly off. Every call to `angular.module(moduleName, dependencies)` will create a new module with those dependencies. While it is a good idea to decompose your angular app into multiple modules, you need to make sure that your root or "main" app that is referenced using the `ng-app` directive has references to all of your sub modules and that any module that references dependencies from another module has that module included in its dependency list.

In your case, you create a module called `newApp.newController`, but as you have it, it will not work because it tries to reference `utilityFactory`, which is defined in a separate module called `newApp.utility`, but is not referenced by your `newApp.newController` module. To fix this, do the following:

```
angular.module('newApp.newController', ['angularSpinner', 'ui.bootstrap', 'newApp.utility']) 
// Make sure to add 'newApp.utility' to the dependencies of the 'newApp.newController' module.
```

Alternatively, you can just create both the controller and the utility factory in the same module:

```
// Create the module once
angular.module('newApp', ['angularSpinner', 'ui.bootstrap']);

// Reference it by invoking it with just one parameter
angular.module('newApp').controller('newController', ...);

angular.module('newApp').factory('utilityFactory', ...);
```

Usage and best practices around the angular module system can be found here:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules